# Does the Infinite Tsukyomi work only on the living?

Tags: naruto

Why does the Infinite Tsukuyomi work only on the living? (As the Edo Tensei Hokages were not affected by it)

Answer (score 4):

The reason why the Infinite Tsukuyomi works only on the living is, **chakra**. The goal of the Infinite Tsukuyomi is to extract chakra/life-force from the host and feed it to the Shinju. By doing this, the Shinju drains the victims' chakra pool and in the end, the victims become White Zetsu. The White Zetsu are then under the control of Kaguya, making them the ideal mindless slaves.

Since non living things do not have chakra, they obviously are of no use to the Shinju or Kaguya. Since the Edo Tensei shinobi are already dead, the "life force" requirement of the Infinite Tsukuyomi isn't not fulfilled.

Along with non living things, the following are also immune to the [Infinite Tsukuyomi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Infinite_Tsukuyomi):

> - Shinobi reincarnated via Summoning: Impure World Reincarnation are not affected by this technique.
> - Black Zetsu is unaffected by the technique, as is anyone he is attached to at the time — namely Obito Uchiha.
> - Those who lack a brain or sensory organs, like White Zetsu.

Comment: You say Edo Tensei have No Chakra so from where was Minato able to share his 9 tails chakra and from where was Hasirama able to fight Madara .All this was not possible without chakra . I  think they didn't have real eyes and that is why were not effected . Tsukyomi is an eternal genjutsu .

Comment: I didn't say Edo Tensei didn't have any chakra. I said: `Edo Tensei shinobi are already dead, the "life force" requirement..`. Infinite Tsukuyomi is a genjutsu, yes. But it doesn't work like normal genjutsu. See this answer: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20151/why-is-everyone-affected-by-infinite-tsukuyomi/20152#20152 Therefore eyes aren't the essential step to trapping people into the genjutsu.

Comment: And Minato was able to share, like you mentioned, *the Nine Tails' chakra*. It doesn't override the Edo Tensei having no life force condition, as Minato uses Kyuubi's chakra and not his own (I doubt if he's able to do it)